# sql query for counting distance travelled

Tags: c#, sql

i have a table like for vehicles and locations

```
time   |  odo
_______
4:00   |   10

5:00   |   20

6:00   |  30

7:00   |  60

8:00   |  80
```

I have another table which has list of vehicles whose time/odo will exist in above table
so I need to pick one vehicle from `vehicleList_table` and do some join on the above table.

so if I query for each vehicle from `vehicleList_table` and start-end time I expect the below result:

say for `starttime` 4:00 and `endtime` 7:00:

```
___
vehicle  |  startTime  |  endTime  |  distanceTravelled
____
MH01k11   4:00        |     7:00     |      50   (i.e 60-10)
___
```

this is wt i need my dataset to have, since i want to show the above output in gridview
is it possible to write a query for the above or do i need to rely on c# code where i have done manual calculation from record retrieved though its complex to load in to gridview

Comment: Please look at the preview while editing your post. You just destroyed other user's editing. Please have a look at [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Yeh that's why I gave you link of the markdown help.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this using a single query:

```
SELECT
  MIN(time)           AS StartTime,
  MAX(time)           AS EndTime,
  MAX(odo) - MIN(odo) AS distanceTravelled
FROM tablename
WHERE time BETWEEN '4:00' 
               AND '8:00';
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fcbfd/1)

---

### Update:

For the output that you are looking for after update your question:

`JOIN` the two tables, and add a `WHERE` clause, this will give you `starttime`, `EndTime` and `distanceTravelled` for each vehicle, with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  v.vehicle,
  MIN(l.time) AS StartTime,
  MAX(l.time) AS EndTime,
  MAX(l.odo) - MIN(l.odo) AS travelled
FROM vehiclelist_table AS v
INNER JOIN locations as l ON v.vehicle_id = l.vehicle_id
WHERE l.time BETWEEN '4:00' AND '7:00'
GROUP BY v.vehicle;
```

[**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ef06/1)

This will give you something like:

```
| VEHICLE | STARTTIME | ENDTIME | TRAVELLED |
---------------------------------------------
| MH01k11 |      4:00 |    7:00 |        50 |
| MHooooo |      4:00 |    7:00 |        50 |
```

If you need to do this for only a specific vehicle add that in the `WHERE` clause.

I also, assumed the columns names and the tables relation, since you didn't provide how they related to each others, you might need to fix the columns' names.

Comment: @downvoter : Please add comment for downvoting. solution seems correct to me.

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal ur super quick man!!! how about if i were to have time intervals in b/w say 5:00 and 7:00 probably with where time >= 5:00 and <=7:00..

Comment: @user1944477 Do you want to do this for more intervals? please update your question with the expected result set that you are looking for in this case. And what RDBMS you are using SQL Server, MySQL or what?

Comment: @Mahmoud is there way to fetch vehicle name from another table and have a (where time (start and End) AND vehicleName = (select distinct vehName from vehInfo_tab) guess do i need to make a JOIN

Comment: @user1944477 That's what my query do, the vehicle name is coming from the `vehiclelist_table` where the time is coming from the locations table, you can also join more tables if you wish. Feel free to updated your question again with the tables structures and the desired output that you want/

Comment: @Mahmoud the table relation is exactly wht u thought, that is i will have vehicleId in both tables and like u did, thats how i wanted to be..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate distance between @Starttime and @Endtime, then you can do this like:

```
Select @Starttime startTime,@Endtime Endtime,Max(odo)-Min(odo)
From YourTable
Where time Between @Starttime And @Endtime
```

Comment: :can you please substitute values in your query ? what i am understanding is in where clause we have to write values like this (' Where time Between '4:00' And '8:00'). So in select how it will identify the `@starttime` and `@endtime`.

Comment: I don't think "Where time Between '4:00' And '8:00'" can have static time here. Starttime And Endtime will be time range which should be passed to query to calculate distance.

Comment: So it would be great if you can provide query with values so that i can come to know something new.

Comment: @ken yes for giving a datetime as variable in between clause is it possible to pass values say for ( where time >= '2012-06-18 04:00:00 AM' and Time <= '2012-06-18 11:59:59 PM')

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  vt.vehiclename as VehicleName
  MIN(ot.time)           AS StartTime,
  MAX(ot.time)           AS EndTime,
  MAX(ot.odo) - MIN(ot.odo) AS distanceTravelled
FROM vehicleTable vt, othertable ot
where vt.vehicleid=ot.vehicleid 
ot.time between time1 and time2
group by vt.vehiclename;
```

Comment: How will you get vehiclename along with aggregate function without group by?